# HTTPD server not starting after disabling these modules mod_include, mod_info, mod_autoindex and mod_userdir

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, php

As per this article "4. Disable Unnecessary Modules"

Ref: http://www.tecmint.com/apache-security-tips/

It’s always good to minor the chances of being a victim of any web attack. So it’s recommended to disable all those modules that are not in use currently. I disabled these modules **mod_imap, mod_include, mod_info, mod_userdir, mod_autoindex**.

After that httpd server is not restarting. Can you please help me to find out the issue?

I didn't get any errors on error_log or access_log.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment - you should open another terminal and run

> journalctl -xe

while attempting to start httpd. Normally service related info is located in the output.

Comment: i tried this but i am not getting anything.. it's show journal is empty

Comment: are you restarting httpd with: systemctl restart httpd ?